# Исправить ошибку js

Tags: javascript

есть такая форма

```
<div class="form-group order-list" id="myTable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label><?=Yii::t('order','text_name'); ?></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <?=Html::dropDownList("name","", $product,['prompt' => Yii::t('main','text_select_values'), 'class' => 'form-control js-example-basic-single', 'required'=>true] ) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label><?=Yii::t('order','text_quantity'); ?></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <?= Html::input('text', 'quantity', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required'=>true]) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label><?=Yii::t('order','text_price'); ?></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <?= Html::input('text', 'price', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required'=>true]) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label><?=Yii::t('order','text_action'); ?></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" id="addrow"><span class="icon-plus-circle2"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <b class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a></b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

по нажатию на кнопочку

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" id="addrow"><span class="icon-plus-circle2"></span></button>`

добавляться формы на js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter = $('#myTable div').length - 2;
        var newRow = $("<div>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<abbr><div class="row">';
        cols += '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="input-group">'.<?=Html::dropDownList("name","", $product,['prompt' => Yii::t('main','text_select_values'), 'class' => 'form-control js-example-basic-single', 'required'=>true] ) ?>.'</div></div>';
        cols += '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity' + counter + '"/></div></div>';
        cols += '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price' + counter + '"/></div></div>';
        cols += '<div class="col-md-1"><div class="input-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon ibtnDel"><span class="icon-minus-circle2"></span></button></div></div>';
        cols += '</div></abbr>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        //if (counter == 4) $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
        $("div.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });
    $("table.order-list").on("change", 'input[name^="price"]', function (event) {
        calculateRow($(this).closest("abbr"));
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });
    $("div.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("abbr").remove();
        calculateGrandTotal();
        counter -= 1
        $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
    });
});
```

Но тут у меня есть ошибка

`cols += '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="input-group">'.<?=Html::dropDownList("name","", $product,['prompt' => Yii::t('main','text_select_values'), 'class' => 'form-control js-example-basic-single', 'required'=>true] ) ?>.'</div></div>';`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Как исправить ошибку ?

Comment: после `'<div class="col-md-4"><div class="input-group">'` идет `.` а потом нет кавычки и в конце

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, это влияние php :-)